# helm lint: INFO Chart.yaml: icon is recommended

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Running helm lint I get:

I get: `[INFO] Chart.yaml: icon is recommended`

Where do I set the icon?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

From [helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-chart-yaml-file):

```
icon: A URL to an SVG or PNG image to be used as an icon (optional).
```

I.e.:

```
apiVersion: v1
description: A Helm chart
name: myChart
version: 0.1.0
icon: https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```

Comment: Note: The link is broken

Comment: You can give any link here for image.

Answer (score 7):

It also support base64 format for the icon:

```
apiVersion: v1
description: A Helm chart
name: myChart
version: 0.1.0
icon: data:image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

And the URL example:

```
apiVersion: v1
description: A Helm chart
name: myChart
version: 0.1.0
icon: https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```