# Where is a helm icon URL used

Tags: icons, kubernetes-helm

A Helm chart may include an `icon` value, which is

> A URL to an SVG or PNG image to be used as an icon

It is optional, but [`helm lint` recommends it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51557965/helm-lint-info-chart-yaml-icon-is-recommended).

But where is this URL used?

- Is it only used during package creation? Does helm download the icon from that URL and incorporate it in the package? In this case, the URL could locate a resource that is not publicly available, such as a `file:` URL for a local source-code file.
- Is it provided like package documentation or meta-data? In this case the URL should locate a publicly available resource. In practice, this means your software needs a web site (or a public GitHub repository, or similar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helm Chart icon is used in web consoles for Helm Charts. For example, if you look at https://hub.helm.sh/, you can find icons. Also OpenShift and IBM Cloud use them in their solutions.

The URL should be a publicly available link, since Helm Package just creates a TGZ with your Chart (not really much more).